# Streaming server error: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = transport is closing"

Tags: go, stream, grpc

I have a server with gRPC stream. And after a client, who had previously subscribed on that stream, unsubscribing, I'm getting this error
`rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = transport is closing`

After I've enabled more detailed logs, I saw this warning
`grpc: Server.Serve failed to create ServerTransport:  connection error: desc = "transport: http2Server.HandleStreams failed to receive the preface from client: EOF"`
And I'm getting it a couple times per second. What can be a problem?

Client

```
stream, err := s.stream.GetStreamClient(metadata.AppendToOutgoingContext(ctx,"key","value"),&sub.StreamRequest{})
for {
   resp, err := stream.Recv()
   if err != nil {
       stream.CloseSend()
       return
}
....
}
```

Client can also call `stream.CloseSend()` after some timeout

Server

```
GetStreamClient(req *sub.StreamRequest, stream pb.StreamClient) error { 
for {
    err := stream.Send()
    if err != nil {
    //log error
    return
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How did you unsubscribe the client?

Comment: @BurakSerdar
I've tried 
`if err :=stream.CloseSend(); err != nil {
...
}`
And by cancelling context, i've passed

Comment: So the client is streaming data to server. Do not cancel the context.

Comment: @BurakSerdar not quite. Client is making an gRPC call to the server, and server starts streaming to client. So client is subscribing. But when client wants to stop consuming messages from server, I'm getting that error on server's side

Comment: Still, do not cancel the context.

Comment: @BurakSerdar I'm not, but it's still the same

Answer (score 0):

Hi and welcome to StackOverflow.

I had this error many times and every time this error was about differences in proto generated in `client` and `server`

e.g: imagine you change your message from:

```
message example {
string var1 = 1;
string var2 = 2;
}
```

to :

```
message example{
string var1 = 1;
int64 var2 = 2;
}
```

and you forgot to regenerate clientside proto code. then the client wants to send var2 as string. but your server side expected as `int64` then your server got panic error and will be closed.

Comment: Hi @ttrasn. I've updated proto schema for both, client and server and I'm still getting same error. So I guess it's not the case here

Comment: @YuraZherebukh No. I think you didnt update generated proto file. are you sure you request exist method ?

Comment: What do you mean `are you sure you request exist method` ? All proto files are in a separate repo, and version hash of imported files are the same in both, client and server.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit late and quite a random shot: I was having a similar issue and it turned out that at some point I was infinitly looping internally and that kept the connection from getting actually closed.

I'm using another version of the grpc, so I can only guess here. But your code suggests that the server will only leave its infinite loop in case of an `error`. Have you checked that closing a stream actually leads to that error?